# Duplicate DNS TXT/SPF records

Tags: dns

So I'm trying to setup a SPF entry on my domain (provided by Gandi).

I already have the following line:

> @ 3600 IN TXT "google-site-verification=[google-verification-code-here]"

which is a line I had to add (or was added automatically) for Google Webmaster Tools.

Now if I try to add the following record (following https://wiki.gandi.net/en/dns/zone/spf-record):

> @ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:217.70.176.0/20 ip6:2001:4b98:c::/48 ptr ?all"

The Gandi manager tells me it already exists. Removing the former "fixes" it, which means the error message refers to it.

Should I mix the two entries somehow, and if so, how?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from the Gandi forums:

**You can have both, but the TTL (3600 vs 10800) have to be the same for both**

Source: http://groups.gandi.net/en/topic/gandi.en.domain.dns/40304